# ipython cv2.imwrite() doesn't work - produces no errors, but also no files

Tags: python, opencv, ipython

I have written some face detection and normalization code - this part takes 20 photos of the face and saves it to a folder.

I have tried several times to make it save but the `cv2.imwrite` doesn't work. It did it once but now it doesn't let me find the photos.

I've already implement some ideas from other problems from stack overflow but it still doesn't work.

When I run the code there are no errors or anything, it just doesn't save the photos.

This is the python code and I run it via ipython notebook:

```js
folder = "C:\Users\John\people" + raw_input('Person: ').lower() # input name
cv2.namedWindow("PyData Tutorial", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
if not os.path.exists(folder):
    os.mkdir(folder)
    counter = 1
    timer = 0
    while counter < 21 : # take 20 pictures
        frame = webcam.get_frame()
        faces_coord = detector.detect(frame) # detect
        if len(faces_coord) and timer % 700 == 50: # every Second or so
            faces = normalize_faces(frame, faces_coord) # norm pipeline
            cv2.imwrite(folder + 'C:\Users\John\people' + str(counter) + '.jpg', faces[0])
            plt_show(faces[0], "Images Saved:" + str(counter))
            clear_output(wait = True) # saved face in notebook
            counter += 1
        draw_rectangle(frame, faces_coord) # rectangle around face
        cv2.imshow("PyData Tutorial", frame) # live feed in external
        cv2.waitKey(50)
        timer += 50
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
else:
    print "This name already exists."
```

Thank you.

Comment: `"C:\Users\John\people"` and `'C:\Users\John\people'` -- you do realize that backslash acts as an [escape character](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), right? So you need to use two backslashes in a sequence (\\\). Also `folder + 'C:\Users\John\people'` doesn't seem to make much sense, considering `folder` is already an absolute path to some directory.

Comment: And just out of curiosity, why not quote the strings consistently? Just because you can use both `"` and `'` doesn't seem like a reason to make a random choice every time.

Comment: try cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/John/people' + str(counter) + '.jpg', faces[0]) ... one hint for debugging filewrite problems is to print and check the output string for errors